# Working of fork

Tags: c++, c

when we use fork, a function is called which creates a process and return two pid (one is parent id and other is child id). How is possible that a function is returning two value? I am not getting it, how fork actually works?

Comment: Whilst this may be a worthwhile question, it's only tangentially a programming question.  It's likely to be more appropriate on [unix.se], but first check whether it's a duplicate of [How do fork and exec work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/179604) or [After fork(), where does the child begin its execution?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/4377).

Answer (score 14):

It's not one function returning two values. It's one function *call* returning *twice*, once in each process, and in each of the two returns, one value is returned. In the parent process, the PID of the child is returned, and in the child process, zero is returned.

Returning twice is the fundamental mechanism by which new processes are created.

Comment: Nice way to phrase it!

Comment: @Dmitry: Thanks, though I think I just pasted that from the manual :-)

Answer (score 0):

fork() does not return two values. fork() returns only one value but, it returns twice. It returns once within the parent process and once within the child process.

For the parent process, the process id of child is returned on success. For the child process, the fork returns 0 and if the child wants to know its own process id, it can be done by using getpid() and if it wants to know its parent, it can be via getppid().

After a fork() system call, there are two independent processes executing the same program text, but with separate copy of segments like stack, data and heap. The pid that is returned by fork() helps in distinguishing whether we are in parent process or child process.

```
pid_t processId;

switch(processId = fork())
{
case -1:
    // Error. Handle error as fork() failed.
case 0:
    // Do actions specific to child.
default :
    // Do actions specific to parent.
}
```